# Defining a General Accessor Callback in V8

Tags: c++, v8

I'm currently integrating V8 and I would like to be notified everytime any property of an object is getting accessed.
I know how to define an accessor for a single property with the SetAccessor method:

```
void v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor    (   Handle< String >    name,
    AccessorGetter      getter,
    AccessorSetter      setter = 0,
    Handle< Value >     data = Handle< Value >(),
    AccessControl   settings = DEFAULT,
    PropertyAttribute   attribute = None     
)
```

I'm wondering if it is also possible to define a general accessor in v8 which is called everytime any property of an object is accessed?
Something like the previous mentioned SetAccessor but without the name argument.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are looking for is called [`SetNamedPropertyHandler`](http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/include/v8.h?r=13335#2447) on the `v8::ObjectTemplate` class. You can trap and intercept (and even prevent creating) any properties on the object this way.